# Python: position of char = word[i]

Tags: python

Previously I write this code:

```
word = input("I am here to cheer for you, enter your name:")
i = 0
a_letters = "bcdgjkpqtuBCDGJKPQTU"
char = word[i]

while i < len(word):

  if char in a_letters: 
      print("Give me a " + char + "!")
  else:
      print("Give me an " + char + "!")
  i += 1
```

But I found that the while loop will not go through each letter of word,
if I enter "max", here is the output:

```
I am here to cheer for you, enter your name:max
Give me an m!
Give me an m!
Give me an m!
```

As I move char = word[i] into while loop:

```
word = input("I am here to cheer for you, enter your name:")

i = 0
a_letters = "bcdgjkpqtuBCDGJKPQTU"


while i < len(word):
  char = word[i]
  if char in a_letters: 
      print("Give me a " + char + "!")
  else:
      print("Give me an " + char + "!")
  i += 1
```

Then the output is what I need:

```
I am here to cheer for you, enter your name:max
Give me an m!
Give me an a!
Give me an x!
```

Just wonder why the position of char = word[i] will make this difference.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because you never change `char` inside the while loop?

Comment: Because in the first example, the `char` in `if char in a_letters` always equals the first letter of the input. The value of `i` does not affect `char` at all after it is assigned.

Comment: What makes you think `char` should change inside the loop, if you call `char = word[i]` outside of the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first one you're not changing the index of word. You just take index 0 and loop through it 3 times. While in the second one with each loop you're incrementing the index by 1

Answer (score 1):

In your `while` loop you are checking `char in a_letters` and then printing `chars`.

You never actually change `cars` in your `while` loop in your first example, therefore `chars` is always the same and keeps printing `m`.

Whereas in your second example, you change `cars`, therefore it keeps on looping through `chars`.

Answer (score 1):

Because in the first example, the `char` in `if char in a_letters` always equals the first letter of the input. The value of `i` does not affect `char` at all after it is assigned, and `i` is 0 at that first assignment.

In your second example, it gets re-assigned each time, so that the value of `i` does affect its value.

You are mistakenly assuming that the evaluation of `char` takes into account the current value of `i` but that is not how variable assignment works.

Something that would work would be making foo a function (in this case, a lambda) instead of a number:

```
word = input("I am here to cheer for you, enter your name:")
i = 0
a_letters = "bcdgjkpqtuBCDGJKPQTU"
char = lambda : word[i]

while i < len(word):

  if char() in a_letters:
      print("Give me a " + char() + "!")
  else:
      print("Give me an " + char() + "!")
  i += 1
```

which would output for example:

```
I am here to cheer for you, enter your name:max
Give me an m!
Give me an a!
Give me an x!
```

In this example, every time the function `foo()` is evaluated, it returns a value that takes the current value of `i` and the current contents of `word` into account.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explaination!! Really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The position of `char = word[i]` makes a difference because when you began, it wasn't in the loop. This resulted in it not being able to update. When you changed it in the loop, it was able to access all parts of the `word =input("I am here to cheer for you, enter your name:")`. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use for loop? it will make your code a lot easier to read and understand.

```
word = input('I am here to cheer you, enter your name: ')
a_letters = "bcdgjkpqtuBCDGJKPQTU"

for char in word:
    if char is in a_letters:
        print("Give me a " + char + "!")
    else:
        print("Give me an " + char + "!")
```

Comment: Ohhh, thanks for that.